# aireplay: I cannot find documentation for numeric modes

Tags: aircrack-ng

I have setup a wep wi-fi and I try to crack it but I have searched the web but I cannot find proped documentation for `aireplay-ng` modes. I mean ok I managed to sniff packets with `airodump-ng` but cannot find a way to figure out the correct mode for `aireplay-ng`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you searched thoughfully? I managed to find the modes in https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-aireplay-ng/

Also do not rely on `--help` option of the command but also on the `man` command as well, the last one offers a good documentation regarding the `aireplay-ng`.